# Model.fit in keras with multi-label classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to learn how to implement my own dataset on the model seen here: [resnet](https://keras.io/examples/cifar10_resnet/) which is just a resnet model written in keras. Within the code they write this line

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
```

and then use the respective data to 'Convert class vectors to binary class matrices.'

```
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
```

and then pass these values into the fit function for the model that was built like so:

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
          shuffle=True,
          callbacks=callbacks)
```

I believe that I can create the x_train by doing something similar to(assumes i have an array of image paths):

```
#pseudocode
x_train = nparray
for image in images:
    im = PIL.Image.open(image).asNumpy() 
    x_train.append(im)
```

Is the above correct?

As for y_train I do not quite understand what is being passed into model.fit, is it an array of one hot encoded arrays? So if I had 3 images containing; a cat and dog, a dog, a cat respectively would the y_train be

```
[
 [1, 1, 0],#cat and dog
 [0, 1, 0],#dog
 [1, 0, 0]#cat
]
```

or am I mistaken on this as well?

Comment: The code implementation looks good. Where's the problem?

Comment: I'm trying to get my own dataset loaded into the model for training on my GPU however I do not quite understand what model.fit() is expecting for x_train and y_train in the above.

Answer (score 2):

So, `model.fit()` expects `x_train` as the features and `y_train` as the labels for a particular classification problem. I'll be taking into consideration **multiclass image classification**.

- `x_train`: For image classification, this argument will have the shape `(num_images, width, height, num_channels )`. Where `num_images` refers to the number of images present in a training batch. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153531/what-is-batch-size-in-neural-network).
- `y_train`: The labels which are one-hot encoded. The required shape is `(num_images, num_classes )`.

> Notice the `num_images` is common in both the arguments. You need to take care to ensure that there is an equal number of images and labels.

Hope that helps.